# Multer upload - files count

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer

I'm trying to handle uploading files count in Multer. My functions looks like:

```
export const upload = multer({
  storage: storage,
  fileFilter: (req, file, callback) =>
    Table.findOne({'user': req.user._id})
      .then(table => {
        if (req.params.type === 'gallery' && table.gallery.length + req.files.length > 10) {
          req.tooManyGalleryImages = true
          return callback(null, false, new Error())
        }

        callback(null, true)
      }),
  limits: {
    fileSize: 2000000
  }
})
```

I need req.files.length but for example if I'm uploading three files it is returning req.files three times with one element array. Maybe is there any other function where I can compare files count before upload?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you can do is utilize the maxCount that is supported in multer.

```
var upload = multer({...}).array('photos', maxCount) //maxCount should be whatever limit you want
upload(req, res, function (err) {
    if (err) {
      // Error due to maxCount will come here
      return
    }

    // Your code
}
```